# NodeJS 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'

Tags: node.js, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I get the above error when I try to connect to a webserver with a node.js client I am writing at te moment.

But I get an error when I try to connect to the server.

`'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'`

This is the code that sends the request. And turning off the certificate check is not a valid option. I need the connection to be secured.

```
var options = 
    {
        hostname: baseUri,
        port: 443,
        path: 'oauth',
        method: 'POST',
        requestCert: true,
        ca:fs.readFileSync('Comodo_PositiveSSL_bundle.crt'),
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        headers: {
            //'User-Agent': USER_AGENT,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': data.length
        }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log('statusCode: ', res.statusCode);
      console.log('headers: ', res.headers);

      res.on('data', (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
      });
    });

    req.write(data)
    req.end();

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
```

If someone can tell me how I can setup the certification correct so no error is generated?

---

Picture of the cert bundle. As you can see the bundle contains only the root certificates need to verify the certificate the server provides itself.

[image: Cert bundle]

Comment: When you open your .crt file, do you see a buffer, or proper text? If it's a buffer I reckon you need to use the actual certificate ( either transform it in node, or use the corresponding .pem file if you have it )

Comment: The file starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` directly, no whitespace before it.

Comment: Then I guess the problem comes from the signing process. Try generating a new one and make sure every field is correct?

Comment: The certificate is a root certificate that we have bought. It is not self signed.

Comment: @VirginieLGB the bundle is the root cert bundle, this bundle is used to verify the certificate the server provides. The certificate the server provides is not included in the bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by the code below. I have added `options.agent = http.Agent(options);`and that solved the problem.

So for everyone who is trying to authenticate to a secure server and gets the error above, this could be your solution. Below I have added the edited code of the above.

```
var options = 
        {
            hostname: baseUri,
            port: 443,
            path: 'oauth',
            method: 'POST',
            requestCert: true,
            headers: {
                //'User-Agent': USER_AGENT,
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Content-Length': data.length
            }
        };
        options.agent = http.Agent(options);

        var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
          console.log('statusCode: ', res.statusCode);
          console.log('headers: ', res.headers);

          res.on('data', (d) => {
            process.stdout.write(d);
          });
        });

        req.write(data)
        req.end();

        req.on('error', (e) => {
          console.error(e);
        });
```

Comment: In your new code, the 'ca' option has disappeared... normal? Also, don't you have any problem using http.Agent and http.request to port 443 instead of https.Agent and https.request?

Comment: `options.agent = new http.Agent(options);` is line that works for me (I added `new`)

Answer (score 1):

This solution is not related to the posted question but for error code of DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT.

Below code throws the same error code

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://10.20.30.40:1234/v1/objects/storages', (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

To solve the problem we have to apply `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"` in https.get(). Kindly look at the problem fixed code in below lines.

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://10.20.30.40:1234/v1/objects/storages',
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0", (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem - it just means Node will ignore certificates.

Answer (score -1):

npm config set strict-ssl false
works for npm managed project

Comment: Can you provide more details on how to apply that configuration? Thank!